# Change input to disabled after other input is selected

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code

```
<form>
    <select name="foo">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="input1" type="text">
    <input name="input2" type="text">
    <input name="input3" type="text">
</form>
```

What I need to happen is when I select Option 1, input1 needs to be disabled. How can I do this with javascript?

Comment: Would you rather have your js find elements or have events in the html?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the selectedIndex of the select

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

document.querySelector("[name=foo]")
  .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    const idx = this.selectedIndex - 1;
    inputs.forEach((input, i) => input.disabled = i === idx);
  });
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="foo">
    <option>---</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text">
  <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text">
  <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Add an event listener to the input event on select element, and use a switch or if statement to change the desired element.

```js
document.querySelector("select")
  .addEventListener("input", e => {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    inputs.forEach(input => input.disabled = false);
    const [in1, in2, in3] = inputs;
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "option1":
        in1.disabled = true;
        break;
      case "option2":
        in2.disabled = true;
        break;
      case "option3":
        in3.disabled = true;
        break;
    }
  });
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="foo">
    <option>---</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text">
  <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text">
  <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onchange="myFunction(this)"` to you select element.
On change of this element, you will fetch the value of the selected option.

As you have the same count of input tags as options so you can replace the string and generate the dynamical name of the element you need to disable.
`var res = val.replaceAll("option", "input");`

```js
function myFunction(selectObject) {

//fetch the value of selected option
var val = selectObject.value; 

var res = val.replaceAll("option", "input");

//remove disabled from all input elements
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(input => input.disabled = false);

//disable the element according to the selected option
document.getElementsByName(res).forEach(e => {
      e.disabled = true;   
    });
};
```

```html
<form>
    <select name="foo" onchange="myFunction(this)">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="input1" type="text">
    <input name="input2" type="text">
    <input name="input3" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: 1. The question is not tagged jQuery. 2. Your jQuery selector is incorrect. 3 Even if it was correct, it is not recommended to use click of options. 4. Not enough code to even understand your answer. Click [edit] and then `[<>]` snippet editor to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan oh yes I misunderstand the question, what I understand is if he clicks or selects any element then the rest of the elements he wants disabled.

Comment: @mplungjan check now